# Spring Boot get the auto configured ObjectMapper instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

In my Spring Boot application, I customize the Jackson ObjectMapper like this:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    
    @Value("${app.dateFormat}")
    private String dateFormat;
    
    @Value("${app.dateFormat} ${app.timeFormat}")
    private String dateTimeFormat;
    
    
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
        return builder -> {
            builder.serializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
            builder.simpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE));
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
        };
    }
}
```

and another bean using ObjectMapper:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext springContext;

@Bean
public ISEAClient createPubClient() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();   
    return new HttpRestSEAClient("http://localhost:8081/sea/", client, springContext.getBean(ObjectMapper.class));
}
```

However, the `ISEAClient` bean still includes null properties when doing JSON serialization.  It seems that the `ObjectMapper` bean is not affected by `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`.

How can I get the same `ObjectMapper` instance used by Spring itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can autowire the builder and then build a new object mapper from the builder.

```
@Autowired
private Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jsonBuilder;

...

@Bean
public ISEAClient createPubClient() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();   
    return new HttpRestSEAClient("http://localhost:8081/sea/", client, jsonBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `@Bean` method in a `@Configuration` class can have other beans injected as arguments. Instead of explicitly getting the bean from context, do this:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {

  @Bean
  public ISEAClient createPubClient(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();   
    return new HttpRestSEAClient("http://localhost:8081/sea/", client, objectMapper);
  }

}
```

Or to get a unique `ObjectMapper` as @JosephGalea suggested, do this:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {

  @Bean
  public ISEAClient createPubClient(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();   
    return new HttpRestSEAClient("http://localhost:8081/sea/", client, builder.build());
  }

}
```